# add a connection with Facebook Login on my app with firebase

Tags: reactjs

I tried to add to my React app a Facebook Login using Firebase.

I get the popup to login but during the connection I get this error on my console.

[image: console]

```
  authenticate = () => {
    const authProvider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider() 
    firebaseApp
    .auth()
    .signInWithPopup(authProvider) 
    .then(this.handleAuth)
  }
```

this is my function to activate my connection to facebook

thank you for help !

Comment: what do you do exactly that makes the popup disappear?

Comment: are you using react native?

Comment: i have the Popup, so I fill in my details, do continue, he is trying to connect to facebook and after few seconds the popup disappear and i have this error on my console ..

Comment: i m not using react native